# authentication using google spreadsheet api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_ruby
I'm following the "Authentication | Using the Google Spreadsheets API" section in above tutorial.

```
 rb(main):008:0> require 'net/https'
    => true
    irb(main):009:0> http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com', 443)
    => #<Net::HTTP www.google.com:443 open=false>
    irb(main):010:0> http.use_ssl = true
    => true
    irb(main):011:0> path = '/accounts/ClientLogin'
    => "/accounts/ClientLogin"

    # Now we are passing in our actual authentication data. 
    # Please visit OAuth For Installed Apps for more information 
    # about the accountType parameter
    irb(main):014:0> data = \
    irb(main):015:0* 'accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=your email' \
    irb(main):016:0* '&Passwd=your password' \
    irb(main):017:0* '&service=wise'

    irb(main):018:0> headers = \
    irb(main):019:0* { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    => {"Content-Type"=>"

application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    # Post the request and print out the response to retrieve our authentication token
    irb(main):020:0> resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
=> #<Net::HTTPLengthRequired 411 Length Required readbody=true>
```

I'm supposed to get "=> [#, "SID=DQAAAIIAAADgV7j4F-QVQjnxdDRjpslHKC3M ... [ snipping out the rest of the authentication strings ]" after the POST. I put my gmail id and password in email and password.
What is problem?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps Have you read? Yes, please take you chance and complaint to google.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that they removed the service today. When I request this page https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin I receive 404 (not found).